# C/GCC: dlopen() without needing dlsym()

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker

I can delay loading of a shared library using dlopen() with [RTLD_NOW](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html). But once library is dynamically loaded, still I need to use dlsym to load each symbols individually.

Since my library contains a large number of APIs, I don't want to call dlsym for all of them. Is there any way to make the APIs work same way as normal loadtime linking (where you just call the APIs without needing dlsym) ?

Comment: You mean without needing to call `dlsym()` *explicitly*?

Comment: Yes, I just need to load the library dynamically. And API calls from application shall work normally - I dont want to rewrite the code to include dlsym() for every APIs.

Comment: I am unmarking this as a duplicate because Linux's shared library semantics are completely different from Windows's shared library semantics; something that is possible on Windows is not necessarily possible on Linux and vice versa.  (For the curious, the difference between [ELF](http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF) and [PE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) executable image formats is what controls, here.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47221988/841108 is an answer to a nearly duplicate question

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for RTLD_GLOBAL.

From the page you linked to[1]:

```
RTLD_GLOBAL
      The symbols defined by this library will be made available for
      symbol resolution of subsequently loaded libraries.
```

By using this, you should be able to create a "wrapper" library around your API that doesn't need to use dlsym(), and in this way cut down on the total number of dlsym() calls needed.  This of course raises the question of whether it's more effort to maintain a wrapper library than to clean up the API.

[1] http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47221988/841108), you could have a plugin which contains an `attribute(constructor)` function registering many plugin functions into some global data structure provided by the main  program (since *constructors* of plugins are called at the `dlopen` time of the plugin). So you could have `dlopen`-ed a plugin and not even use `dlsym` once to retrieve and use (many) plugin functions.

> I need to use dlsym to load each symbols individually.

Wrong. `dlsym` *finds* functions (or data) by their symbol (or name). The function is already here (since the entire code segment of the plugin is added into your virtual address space by `dlopen`).

Answer (score 0):

Probly not relevant anymore but still - you are looking for analog of Windows DLL import libraries which would provide stubs that look like normal functions to your code but call `dlopen` and `dlsym` internally.

Linux does not provide import libraries out-of-the-box but you can generate them by hand, via some custom script or use [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so) tool to do this fully automatically.