# Is there an elegant way to avoid dlsym when using dlopen in C?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, function-pointers, dlopen

I need to dynamically open a shared library `lib.so` if a specific condition is met at runtime. The library contains ~700 functions and I need to load all their symbols.

A simple solution is to define the function pointers to all symbols contained in `lib.so`, load the library using `dlopen` and finally get the addresses of all symbols using `dlsym`. However, given the number of functions, the code implementing this solution is very cumbersome.

I was wondering if a more elegant and concise solution exists, maybe with an appropriate use of macros for defining the function pointers. Thanks!

Comment: If you need to call 700 functions from a shared library why not just have one function in the shared library that calls those functions for you? Such a list would be easier to maintain inside the library rather than in macros outside.

Comment: Actually the application is a profiler which intercepts the calls of another library `lib_ext.so` and replace them with its profiled version defined in `lib.so`. The symbols of `lib_ext.so` are overloaded using the LD_PRELOAD variable. 
Since I do not know in advance which functions of `lib_ext.so` will be called at runtime I need the addresses of all symbols.

Comment: @n.m. You are right about `dlsym`. I changed the text of the question.

Comment: It's still unclear why you would need all the addresses.

Comment: @n.m. Because I do not know in advance which functions in `lib.so` will be called and if there is one address missing then the corresponding function will not be correctly profiled.

Comment: I'd propose to write a tool creating the relevant C code for you, that is defining all the correctly typed function pointers along with all the calls to `dlopen()`.

Comment: So you have some kind of a profiler and you want to add each function address to the profiler before running any code in the library, is this correct? Does it require to register all functions you want to profile ahead of time? If so, you have a vey unusual and hostile profiler. Perhaps you misunderstand what it does?

Comment: @n.m. It is a profiler for a MPI application. It does not instrument the code and it profiles only a known set of functions (those defined by the MPI API). Therefore I guess I really need to register all function addresses. As you say I might have misunderstood anyway.

Comment: @alk I thought about that too. If I did not find any other solution I will write the external generator as you propose. Thanks!

Comment: If you're intercepting function calls, you need more than just the address of the function.  How do you handle arguments?  What about return values?

Comment: @AndrewHenle The arguments and return values of the functions are given by the MPI API so I already know them.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it and explain why do you ask and how to you use `dlopen`  and what are your program and its plugin doing. Add a few sentences on motivation and context.

Answer (score 14):

You could automatically generate trampoline functions for all symbols in `dlopen`-ed library. Trampolines would be seen as normal functions in application but would internally redirect to real code in library. Here's a simple 5-minute PoC:

```
$ cat lib.h
// Dynamic library header
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H
extern void foo(int);
extern void bar(int);
extern void baz(int);
#endif

$ cat lib.c
// Dynamic library implementation
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int x) {
  printf("Called library foo: %d\n", x);
}

void bar(int x) {
  printf("Called library baz: %d\n", x);
}

void baz(int x) {
  printf("Called library baz: %d\n", x);
}

$ cat main.c
// Main application
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <lib.h>

// Should be autogenerated
void *fptrs[100];
void init_trampoline_table() {
  void *h = dlopen("./lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  fptrs[0] = dlsym(h, "foo");
  fptrs[1] = dlsym(h, "bar");
  fptrs[2] = dlsym(h, "baz");
}

int main() {
  init_trampoline_table();
  printf("Calling wrappers\n");
  foo(123);
  bar(456);
  baz(789);
  printf("Returned from wrappers\n");
  return 0;
}

$ cat trampolines.S
  // Trampoline code.
  // Should be autogenerated. Each wrapper gets its own index in table.
  // TODO: abort if table wasn't initialized.

  .text

  .globl foo
foo:
  jmp *fptrs(%rip)

  .globl bar
bar:
  jmp *fptrs+8(%rip)

  .globl baz
baz:
  jmp *fptrs+16(%rip)

$ gcc -fPIC -shared -O2 lib.c -o lib.so
$ gcc -I. -O2 main.c trampolines.S -ldl
$ ./a.out
Calling wrappers
Called library foo: 123
Called library baz: 456
Called library baz: 789
Returned from wrappers
```

Note that application code in `main.c` is using only local functions (which wrap library functions) and does not have to mess with function pointers at all (apart from initializing redirection table at startup which should be autogenerated code anyway).

**EDIT:** I've created a standalone tool [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so) to automate creation of stub libraries like in example above. This turned out to be more or less equivalent to well known Windows DLL import libraries.

Comment: I don't understand how your solution could work with a library open with dlopen or you sure of your solution ?

Comment: @Stargateur I originally wrote PoC which didn't use shlibs to illustrate the idea but your comment motivated me to rewrite it, hopefully my intent is more clear now. Note that I hope to do mini-project soon to have a fully working solution and I'll post a link here.

Comment: @Stargateur I've added link to generic tool I promised.

Comment: The solutions looks amazing but I got error when trying: 

`gcc -fPIC -shared -O2 lib.c -o lib.so`  
`gcc -I. -O2 main.c trampolines.S -ldl`     

Error: `/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfZfE32.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol 'fptrs' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE`

Comment: @Rick thank you for noticing this. Modern distros compile executables with -fPIE flag by default which required some changes in assembly code in trampolines.S. I've updated the answer.

Comment: It works now. It's like magic. What kind of CS knowledge should one learn in order to 
understand and write a `.S` file ?  x86_64 assembly?

Comment: @rick yes, the assembly here is simple so assembly primer like [this one](https://gist.github.com/AVGP/85037b51856dc7ebc0127a63d6a601fa) should be enough.

Comment: @Rick note that there is now a [tool](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so) for generating the wrappers which hides all the details.

Answer (score 9):

> I need to dynamically open a shared library lib.so if a specific condition is met at runtime. The library contains ~700 functions and I need to load all their symbols.

#### role of `dlopen` and `dlsym`

When you `dlopen` a library, all the functions defined by that library becomes available in your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (because all the code segment of that library is added into your virtual address space by [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) calling [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) several times). So `dlsym` don't add (or load) any additional code, it is already there. If your program is running in the process of pid 1234, try `cat /proc/1234/maps`  after the successful `dlopen`.

What `dlsym` provides is the ability to get the address of something in that shared library from its name, using some dynamic [symbol table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) in that [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) plugin. If you don't need that, you don't need to call `dlsym`.

Perhaps you could simply have, in your shared library, a large array of all the relevant functions (available as a global variable in your shared library). Then you'll just need to call `dlsym` once, for the name of that global variable.

BTW, a *constructor* (`constructor` is a [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html)) function of your plugin could instead "register" some functions of that plugin (into some global data structure of your main program; this is how [Ocaml dynamic linking](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.06/libdynlink.html) works); so it even makes sense to never call `dlsym` and still be able to use the functions of your plugin.

For a plugin, its *constructor* functions are called at `dlopen` time (before the `dlopen` returns!) and its *destructor* functions are called at `dlclose` time (before `dlclose` returns).

#### repeating calls to `dlsym`

It is common practice to use `dlsym` many times. Your main program would declare several variables (or other data e.g. fields in some `struct`, array components, etc...) and fill these with `dlsym`. Calling `dlsym` a few hundred times is really quick. For example you could declare some global variables

```
void*p_func_a;
void*p_func_b;
```

<sup>(you'll often declare these as pointers to functions of appropriate, and perhaps different, types; perhaps [use `typedef` to declare signature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9143434/841108)s)</sup>

and you'll load your plugin with

```
void*plh = dlopen("/usr/lib/myapp/myplugin.so", RTLD_NOW);
if (!plh) { fprintf(stderr, "dlopen failure %s\n", dlerror()); 
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

then you'll fetch function pointers with

```
p_func_a = dlsym(plh, "func_a");
if (!p_func_a) { fprintf(stderr, "dlsym func_a failure %s\n", dlerror());
                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
p_func_b = dlsym(plh, "func_b");
if (!p_func_b) { fprintf(stderr, "dlsym func_b failure %s\n", dlerror());
                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

<sup>(of course you could use preprocessor macros to shorten such repetitive code; [X-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) tricks are handy.)</sup>

Don't be shy in calling `dlsym` hundreds of times. It is however important to *define* and *document* appropriate *conventions* regarding your plugin (e.g. explain that every plugin should define `func_a` and `func_b` and when are they called by your main program (using `p_func_a` etc... there). If your *conventions* require hundreds of different names, it is a bad smell.

#### agglomerating plugin functions into a data structure

So assume your library defines `func_a`, `func_b`, `func_c1`, ... `func_c99` etc etc you might have a global array (POSIX allows casting functions into `void*` but the C11 standard does not allow that):

```
const void* globalarray[] = {
  (void*)func_a,
  (void*)func_b,
  (void*)func_c1,
  /// etc
  (void*)func_c99,
  /// etc
  NULL /* final sentinel value */
};
```

and then you'll need to `dlsym` only *one* symbol: `globalarray`; I don't know if you need or want that. Of course you could use more fancy data structures (e.g. mimicking [vtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) or operation tables).

---

#### using a *constructor* function in your plugin

With the constructor approach, and supposing your main program provides some `register_plugin_function` which do appropriate things (e.g. put the pointer in some global hash table, etc...), we would have in the plugin code a function declared as

```
static void my_plugin_starter(void) __attribute__((constructor));
void my_plugin_starter(void) {
  register_plugin_function ("func", 0, (void*)func_a);
  register_plugin_function ("func", 1, (void*)func_b);
  /// etc...
  register_plugin_function ("func", -1, (void*)func_c1);
  /// etc...
};
```

and with such a constructor the `func_a` etc... could be `static` or with restricted [visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility). We then don't need any call to `dlsym` from the main program (which should provide the `register_plugin_function` function) loading the plugin.

---

### references

Read more carefully [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) and [plug-ins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) and [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) wikipages. Read Levine's [*Linkers and Loaders*](http://iecc.com/linker/) book. Read [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html), [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html), [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html). Play with [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html), [nm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html), [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html).

Of course read Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper.

BTW, you can call `dlopen` then `dlsym` a big lot of times. My [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) program is generating "random" C code, compiling it as a plugin, then `dlopen`-ing and `dlsym`-ing it, and repeats. It demonstrates that (with patience) you can have millions of plugins `dlopen`-ed in the same process, and you can call `dlsym` a lot of times.

Comment: On POSIX it is explicitly not UB, and `dlsym` is POSIX specific.

Comment: "If you don't need that, you don't need to call dlsym" - but how would he access functions then? Note that explicitly referencing a function name in code is not possible because it'll cause linker errors (symbol is only available at runtime).

Comment: As I told, the plugin could register some function pointers in some constructor function

Comment: "As I told, the plugin could register some function pointers in some constructor function" - isn't OP asking for solution which does not use function pointers?

Comment: Have you exactly understood what the OP wants? I did not yet (and I believe OP is very confused). I only made educated guess. I'm sad that so many questions stay unmotivated and without context.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358255/841108 which explains my sadness. This question is another example... But my opinion (about insufficient motivations) is in the minority.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point now. Our answers seem to stem from different understanding of the question then.

Comment: @yugr: at least we both agree that the OP's question is poorly asked and lacks motivation and context. I voted to close that question because it is unclear. Perhaps the OP would improve it (but I am not optimistic).

Comment: Yes. But it's still an interesting question.

Comment: We disagree. I find the OP's question boring, because we need to guess his intents and try to read in his mind. For me it is not an interesting question, just a poorly asked and too broad one!

Answer (score -1):

Refer to [difference between dynamic loading and dynamic linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052464/difference-between-dynamic-loading-and-dynamic-linking)
, you may need **dynamic linking** instead of **dynamic loading** a shared library.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).