# Loading derived polymorphic class using dlopen

Tags: c++, linux, linker, dynamic-linking, dlopen

In a C++ code I'm trying to have a main module that defines a polymorphic base class, which dynamically loads derived classes for it at runtime. The main module has something like:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual int f() = 0;
};

int main() {
    auto make_a_ptr = /* load function pointer make_a from module using dsym */;
    Base* a = make_a_ptr();
    std::cout << a->f() << std::endl;
    delete a;
}
```

The dynamically loaded external module has:

```
class A : public Base {
public:
    int f() {
        return 123;
    }
};

extern "C" Base* make_a() {
    return new A;
}
```

Will a system like this work on Linux, without additional steps regarding the dynamic linking? Because here only `make_a` is explicitly loaded using `dlsym()`, but the main module will also call `A::f()` and `A::~A()`, and access the v-table of `A`. Will this still work even though those symbols were not explicitly loaded?

And is a similar system possible on Windows platform?

Comment: Plugins on Windows work differently, and could need `dllimport` and `dllexport` annotations for functions of your main program used by plugins. That makes a *huge* difference. BTW, your system works on Linux because you linked the main program with `-rdynamic`. Read Levine's [Linkers and loaders](https://www.iecc.com/linkers/) book. Be aware of name mangling.

Comment: standard library has to be linked dynamically for dll and host application, otherwise each part will have own heap and you can have problems during cleanup.

Comment: "_call A::f() and A::~A(),_" Specifically, you will use the deleting `A::~A()`, the function performing `delete a_ptr;` virtually. It's a different destructor entry. (Compile with vtable printing. Or check the asm code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In a C++ code I'm trying to have a main module that defines a polymorphic base class, which dynamically loads derived classes for it at runtime.

So far, so good. Beware all the usual caveats - among them are:

- Use the same compiler and library versions when compiling plugins. At the very least make sure the ABIs are compatible.
- Link to a shared c++ runtime when doing this on windows.
- windows will require `ddlexport`/`dllimport` attributes on declarations.
- compile linux shared libraries with -fPIC
- be sure to lazy-load symbol names so as to avoid conflicts (e.g. if 2 shared libs have an exported function called `make_a`.

> Will a system like this work on Linux, without additional steps regarding the dynamic linking?

Yes

> And is a similar system possible on Windows platform?

Yes. Again, see caveats and do some research.

Some good answers here: [Is there an elegant way to avoid dlsym when using dlopen in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917816/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-avoid-dlsym-when-using-dlopen-in-c/47221180)